# React Bootstrap Only Allow One Checkbox Tick

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-forms

I'm using React bootstrap within a functional component for a table. In this table I have one entry which has two checkboxes, I want to allow only one of them to be ticked. When I select one, I would like another table entry to change. Here is my code:

```
    <td>
                          <Form>
                            {["checkbox"].map(type => (
                              <div
                                key={`custom-inline-${type}`}
                                className="mb-3"
                              >
                                <Form.Check
                                  custom
                                  inline
                                  label="Exponential"
                                  type={type}
                                  id={`custom-inline-${type}-1`}
                                />
                                <Form.Check
                                  custom
                                  inline
                                  label="Polynomial"
                                  type={type}
                                  id={`custom-inline-${type}-2`}
                                />{" "}
                              </div>
                            ))}
                          </Form>
    </td>
```

And I have two options in a separate entry that will change based on whether the user selected "Polynomial" or "Exponential" - either

```
<td> Ax^2 + Bx + c </td>
```

or

```
<td> Ax^n </td>
```

How can I do this? I would like to avoid radio buttons and those dependencies if possible.

Edit: I've managed to add some radio buttons from Bootstrap, but I'm not sure how to return the function in `<td>`.

```
  const [exp, setExp] = useState(true);
  const [poly, setPoly] = useState(false);

  function onExpChange() {
    console.log("exp triggered");
    setExp(true);
    setPoly(false);
  }

  function onPolyChange() {
    console.log("poly triggered");
    setPoly(true);
    setExp(false);
  }
```

And in the table:

```
                          <Form>
                            <ToggleButtonGroup
                              type="radio"
                              name="distribution"
                              defaultValue={"exponential"}
                            >
                              <ToggleButton
                                value={"exponential"}
                                onChange={onExpChange}
                              >
                                Exponential
                              </ToggleButton>
                              <ToggleButton
                                value={"polynomial"}
                                onChange={onPolyChange}
                              >
                                Polynomial
                              </ToggleButton>
                            </ToggleButtonGroup>
                          </Form>
```

Comment: Does the Form.Check not have a prop called checked which you will manually have to pass tot eh Check to let it know if it is or isn't and that's based on the onChange or onChecked cant mind what it was being hit?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted....

```
  const [exp, setExp] = useState(true);
  const [poly, setPoly] = useState(false);

  function onExpChange() {
    console.log("exp triggered");
    setExp(true);
    setPoly(false);
  }

  function onPolyChange() {
    console.log("poly triggered");
    setPoly(true);
    setExp(false);
  }

  function expectedGoals() {
    if (exp === true) {
      return "Expected Goals = A3x^3 + A2x^2 + A1x + A0";
    } else {
      return "something else";
    }
  }
```

And the table entries:

```
<td>
<Form>
  <ToggleButtonGroup
    type="radio"
    name="distribution"
    defaultValue={"exponential"}
  >
    <ToggleButton
      value={"exponential"}
      onChange={onExpChange}
    >
      Exponential
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton
      value={"polynomial"}
      onChange={onPolyChange}
    >
      Polynomial
    </ToggleButton>
  </ToggleButtonGroup>
</Form>
</td>

<td>{expectedGoals()}</td>
```

Thanks for today.